# instead of getting a download of a csv export from database, write via ftp to a server

Tags: php

Ok so I have a script that runs and makes a csv file from my database, when it runs from the browser it downloads, fine.

But I want to publish the file to another server from my server.

I've been trying to do it with this code, but it doesn't appear to work, there is no file written. Log in OK comes back even if the FTP account details are wrong too..

```
// header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
// header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sailings.txt");
// header("Pragma: no-cache");
// header("Expires: 0");
// print "$header\n$data";

//Connect to the FTP server
$ftpstream = ftp_connect('ftp server address');

//Login to the FTP server
$login = ftp_login($ftpstream, 'user', 'password');
if($login) {
echo "logged in ok";
//We are now connected to FTP server.
//Create a temporary file
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $header."\n");
fwrite($temp, $data);
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 0);

//Upload the temporary file to server
ftp_fput($ftpstream, '/sailings.txt', $temp, FTP_ASCII);

//Make the file writable only to owner
ftp_site($ftpstream,"CHMOD 0644 /sailings.txt");
}

//Ftp session end
fclose($temp);
ftp_close($ftpstream);
```

Please can anyone advise me ?

thanks

Rich :)

Comment: Are you sure there is indeed a connection? Try testing $ftpstream for false before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the tmpfile function returns the handle of the file, and the ftp_put function needs to receive the path + name of the file that is going to be uploaded.  In this sense, you have a mismatch in the operation of these 2 instructions.

To solve this:

```
$f = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
$temp = = fopen($f, "w");
fwrite($temp, $header."\n");
fwrite($temp, $data);
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 0);

//Upload the temporary file to server
ftp_put($ftpstream, '/sailings.txt', $f, FTP_ASCII);

// The rest is the same as you have
```

Try this solution and good luck

**EDIT**:  Thanks to Felipe comments.  You are using the **ftp_fput** properly.  Nevertheless, if your problem persist and you still get stucked, you may use the strategy given to see what happens.

Comment: `ftp_fput ( resource $ftp_stream , string $remote_file , **resource $handle** , int $mode [, int $startpos = 0 ] )` From PHP 5 Manual

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA what is your source?  From http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php I read:  bool ftp_put ( resource $ftp_stream , string $remote_file , string $local_file , int $mode [, int $startpos = 0 ] ) where $local_file is:  "The local file path."

Comment: We are talking about different functions: ftp_put vs ftp_fput. The OP code includes the last one.

Comment: That could happen to anybody. Nothing to worry about, maybe you should delete your answer before it gets downvoted. That is, if there are no new ideas.